# How to get int buffer-memory of String in JAVA?

Tags: java, android, c, string, pointers

I know that Java is no C, so no pointers and direct usable addresses but still I need it, because of the given library.

The library `Andglk` has been ported from native C and whoever did it, has the following constructor declaration in one of the classes:

```
public LineInputEvent(Window w, String s, int lineBuffer, 
                                              long maxLen, int dispatchRock, boolean unicode)
```

I now want to create one such event, but have no idea how to specify the `lineBuffer`. About the `dispatchRock` - it is also problematic but I believe it is not the bigger problem here.

Basically, this int `lineBuffer` (as the `dispatchRock`) is used one for all events during a session. One example is `1405421324` for all inputs.

About it (in the C documentation, there is for now almost nothing about `andglk`) is said:

> This text will be placed in a buffer of your choice.

Any idea how can I specify it in Java for a given String?

EDIT:

This is from the `andglk.c`:

```
int andglk_loader_glk_MemoryStream_retainVmArray(JNIEnv *env, jobject this, int buffer, long length)
{
    if (gli_register_arr) {
        gidispatch_rock_t rock = gli_register_arr((void *)buffer, length, gidispatch_char_array);
        return rock.num;
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're working with a Java *wrapper* for Anglek that accesses Anglek functions via JNI.  This is very different from a port, and that difference matters.  In particular, are we to assume that `lineBuffer` corresponds to a C pointer to a buffer?  That's plausible for a wrapper, but very unlikely for a *bona fide* port.

Comment: Also, do you have any hope or expectation that your code will run in 64-bit VMs?